# How can we recognize two excel.exe proceeses opened by different object?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, exe, wsh

I have an .vbs file which is working on an Excel workbook. now suppose a situation arsie where in the system 3 EXCEL.EXE processes are running.So now is there any way to find out which one is opened by a main.vbs script?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you tagged this powershell, here's a VBS only option will may need some tinkering depending on your Excel version (I have 2003 on this pc):

```
'Create Excel Application for demo purposes only
Dim ex: Set ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strList

strComputer = "." 'Change if you want to run on another computer

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

'Look only at Excel process name
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where NAME = 'EXCEL.exe'")

'Get the list of Processes, included only for demo purposes
For Each objProcess In colProcess
    strList = strList & vbCr & objProcess.commandline
Next
MsgBox strList ' Displayed "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\EXCEL.EXE"
                          '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\EXCEL.EXE" / automation - Embedding
               ' Second row was the created Object.

'Find processes that match the Created Object format commandline
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where CommandLine Like '%EXCEL.exe"" /automation -Embedding'")
For Each objProcess In colProcess
    'Do something with process
    objProcess.Terminate
Next
'Next line will cause runtime error due to process already being terminated.
ex.Quit
```

The beauty of methods similar to this is that by using the objProcess.Commandline you can find command-line switches sent to the application which you can use to pinpoint a specific process. For instance, if you had a .bat file that opened an Excel file like this : `start Excel.exe C:\example.xls` the process would include `C:\example.xls` within the process Commandline property.

Comment: i have a doubt! my script will run over across the world,So its very hard for me to get the value of `strComputer` . Any chance to avoid the same?

Comment: How could you ever run a script on a computer if you don't know what computer it's running on? I guess I don't understand the question. The `.` will refer to the computer upon which the script is running.

Comment: let myself clear on this point. Shall I need to provide "computer" name on that parameter? and FYI I am using EXCEL 2010

Comment: You would only need to change the parameter if you want to run it on a machine other than the computer running the script. I didn't realize I wasn't clear.

Comment: what the `strComputer = "."` line stands for? why `"."`?

Comment: Have you looked at the link provided by vonPryz? That page clearly explains what I'm trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Get-WMIObject win32_process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a list of all the processes. Look at `ParentProcessId` member to see which process has spawned which Excel instance.

VBScripts are executed via WScript or CScript, so you need to look at the correct parent first.

Be aware that Windows does recycle process ids. That is, at time t0 pid 1000 is not necessarily the same process as at time t1.

**Addendum:**

Use `-Computername` switch to specify another a computer for the WMI query. If no `-Computername` switch is present, localhost is assumed. Local host is also known as `.`, which was used in the VBScript answer above. Like so,

```
#Get process list from Server01, assuming you have sufficient rights
Get-WMIObject win32_process -Computername server01
```

Comment: i want to run this script globally,so how could I be able to give their computer names there,as the `code` mentioned in your link.please guide here

Comment: Excel runs as a COM server with ppid = winlogon.exe, not the VBS process.